# How to prove $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration

How to prove $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

How do I proceed?

Comment: That has been asked like a thousand times on MSE.

Comment: If a thousand people asked how to prove it, surely it is true.

Comment: wow thanks a lot